# Error while trying upload Artifact to Nexus 2.9

Tags: java, nexus

I'm updating some POMs and artifacts to a Nexus server 2.9.

Then I got this message:

> Artifact upload failed. Could not store item to repository "Releases" [id=releases], path ResourceStoreRequest{requestPath='/br/com/x/core/x-core/1.8.0/x-core-1.8.0.pom', requestContext=RequestContext{this=org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.RequestContext@6f0b29b1, parent=null}, pathStack=[], processedRepositories=[], appliedMappings={}}(GAVCE=br.com.x.core:x-core:1.8.0:c=null:e=jar, for "Releases" [id=releases])

Comment: Hey @Arthur. Did this work out for you?

Comment: The main cause of this problem seems to be some cyclic references. But I didn't know that Nexus doesn't allow released artifacts to be changed, and I lose sometime in this situation. Thanks for help @Alexander .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean with "update"? Do you try to overwrite version 1.8.0 of your artifact `x-core-1.8.0.pom`, or do you want to deploy the new version 1.8.0?

Nexus doesn't allow *released* artifacts to be changed - that's what a *snapshot* repository is for. See [Is Release repository policy in Nexus ensures a jar will never change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391820/is-release-repository-policy-in-nexus-ensures-a-jar-will-never-change)

If you want to do changes to an already released version, you have to upgrade the version number, too! E.g. to 1.8.1 or 1.9.0.

If you really want to change a released artifact afterwards (and if you have **a good reason for it**), you'll have to delete the artifact first before you can redeploy it.